# Adding if statement to content for homepage

Tags: php, loop, homepage

I have an if statement already in my loop to display content based on post type. I was wondering if there was a way that I could say to ignore that section if it is the front page/homepage. Here's a sample of my code:

```
    <?php if( get_post_type() == 'reviews' ) { ?>

<div class="post-review">

                <div class="review-score">

            other div stuff

            </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for `is_front_page()` and if you want to catch the first page only inspect `get_query_var( 'paged' )` too:

```
if ( is_front_page() and 2 > get_query_var( 'paged' ) )
{
    // we are on the first page of the front page
}
```